# Does the TLS(Transport Layer Security) standard needs any change when .net framework version is upgraded to 4.8?

Tags: tls1.2, .net-4.8, tls1.3, target-framework

I am upgrading the .Net Projects TargetFramework version from lower versions(2.0, 3, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2...) to higher Framework version(v4.8). This I am able to do this project upgrade in simple way, but I want to understand what is the impact of this on TLS standard version and what are the additional changes I need to do in upgraded project for TLS?

Comment: Which version exactly are you upgrading from? 3.5? 4.0? or 4.6? Something else?

Comment: And what version of TLS are you currently using/requiring in your app?

Comment: I have different .net projects with following lower framework versions 2.0, 3, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2

Comment: Currently in projects source code no specific TLS versions are set

Comment: OK, so you are just asking how to target/require TLS 1.2 in your apps now that you're upgrading them all to 4.8?

Comment: There are lots of good questions on SO already that cover this: https://www.google.com/search?q=forcing+TLS+1.2+in+.NET+4.8+site:stackoverflow.com